# Construct a bipartite representation of a directed network for use with hopcroft-karp matching function in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, matching, bipartite

I am using the hopcroft-karp algorithm in networkx on a directed network which I have transformed into a bipartite representation. However, the bipartite network is not allowed to have the same vertex in both left and right node sets. There is a self loop included in my directed network, so as a workaround, I rename the vertices in the left node set as (X1_+, X2_+,X3_+) and in the right set as (X1_-,X2_-,X3_-). The directed network and the corresponding bipartite representation are as follows:

[image]

The correct result for the maximum matching, in terms of the dictionary output given by the hopcroft-karp algorithm in networkx, should be

`{X2-:X1+,X3-:X3+)]` so that `X1-` would be the only unmatched node since it does not appear as a key in the output dictionary.

I followed the networkx documentation to get the corresponding bipartite network and then I used the hopcroft-karp function to obtain the maximum matching. The code that i implemented is outlined below along with the result:

```
# Add nodes w/ the node attribute bipartite
G_eg.add_nodes_from(["X1_+", "X3_+"], bipartite=1)
G_eg.add_nodes_from(["X2_-", "X3_-"], bipartite=0)
# Add edges only between nodes of opposite node sets
G_eg.add_edges_from([("X1_+", "X2_-"), ("X1_+", "X3_-"), ("X3_+", "X3_-")])

#left, right nodes based on node attribute
left_nodes = {n for n, d in G_eg.nodes(data=True) if d["bipartite"] == 1}
right_nodes = set(G_eg) - left_nodes

#apply hopcroft-karp algorithm
nx.bipartite.hopcroft_karp_matching(G_eg, left_nodes)
```

output:

`{'X3_+': 'X3_-', 'X1_+': 'X2_-', 'X3_-': 'X3_+', 'X2_-': 'X1_+'}`

From my output, I can see that `X1_-` is not listed as a key and therefore it is deemed unmatched. However, why is it that the output gives the result in this way, meaning, it ignores the fact that the network is directed. By including `X1_+:X2_-` in the output dictionary, it implies that `X1_+` is matched. Is my interpretation incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, any directions you impose on the edges of the graph are ignored by `hopcroft_karp_matching` (and the other implementations of `maximum_matching`). Regarding the format of the output, [the documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.matching.hopcroft_karp_matching.html#networkx.algorithms.bipartite.matching.hopcroft_karp_matching) specifies that the output is

> **matches** – The matching is returned as a dictionary, `matches`, such that `matches[v] == w` if node `v` is matched to node `w`. Unmatched nodes do not occur as a key in `matches`.

In particular, the matched notes are exactly the keys of the directory, in your case `{'X3_+', 'X1_+', 'X3_-', 'X2_-'}`. In particular, this means that the output could always be cut in half, with matched nodes being available as the union of keys and values; I assume the redundant information is included simply because it might be convenient in some cases.